# PHP: Counting entries in a loop and using them in a calculation

Tags: php

I have a loop in PHP as follows:

```
$getDetails = mssql_query ("SELECT * FROM BasketItems 
WHERE BasketID = '".$_GET['id']."' ");

while ($detailsrow = mssql_fetch_array($getDetails)) {     
  $TotalSetPrice = $detailsrow['FinalPrice'] * $detailsrow['Qty'];
  echo $TotalSetPrice;

  $numberofent = count($detailsrow['FinalPrice']);
  echo "######NUMBER#####: $numberofent";

  $TotalPrice = ?????;

  ######VARIOUS DATA##############
}
```

So ok i'm not an expert at PHP by any means, thats the first thing. `FinalPrice` is the price of an item in the DB that someone has selected. However the customer can have any number of quantity of those items.

So `FinalPrice * Qty = TotalSetPrice`

However the customer may also have different sets of items within the basket.

So I need to calculate `TotalSetPrice * (Number of sets of items Within the DB)`

SO I googled, and came up with count(), but if I just `count($detailsrow)` it returns `56` entries, this is the number of overall pieces of data if that makes sense. I just want to count the dumber of actual data sets. I tried counting `finalprice` but that just returns `1`, which isn't correct either.

Can anyone give me some guidence on how you are meant to count the number of entries in an array loop such as this. I hope that makes more sense than I feel it does.

Comment: Please post more information about the table structure.

Comment: A much better solution would be to perform the calculation in your SQL query. That avoids bringing ALL the data downstream just to do a calculation that the database can do for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into mssql queries and calculations, what information about the table structure would help?

Comment: $detailsrow is only the array where your DB-rows are saved in. I think you should use count() in your SQL to count the number of sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT FinalPrice, Qty,(FinalPrice * Qty) AS TotalSetPrice

Just use mysql, so that you no longer use with php which you will need to write a longer code

Comment: Knowing nothing else about the table structure I would say this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$TotalPrice += $TotalSetPrice;
```

This is short for: `$TotalPrice = $TotalPrice + $TotalSetPrice;`

Comment: This is making my brain hurt, how can I use $TotalPrice in a calculation to determine the value of $TotalPrice? When $TotalPrice isn't defined already...

Comment: Add $TotalPrice = 0; before the loop. Might make some more sense.

Comment: But wouldn't that just set $TotalPrice as the same Value as TotalSetPrice?

Comment: @ObjectiveJ wouldn't iterations in the while loop add each `$TotalSetPrice` to the `$TotalPrice`.